# visual studio: tab markers (as in sublimetext)

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext2

I am working with visual studio.
I was wondering if it would be possible to have those thin vertical lines as in sublimetext (image below): working in F# that would be very useful.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extension called [Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30) that might be what you are looking for.